# Why can I connect to '127.0.0.1' but not 'localhost' when no internet connection is present in MongoDB compass?

Tags: mongodb

I am curious why I can connect to the localhost server by specifying the loopback IP address (127.0.0.1) but not using the name 'localhost', when no internet connection is present in mongoDB compass? When I try to connect with the domain name I get the following error:

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017

I'm guessing the domain name lookup process is requiring the internet in order to convert localhost to 127.0.0.1. Not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Just trying to guess: when you connect to the internet the DNS resolver handles the `localhost` name resolution. If you add an entry to `/etc/hosts` should work without the connection.

Comment: I just tried this with hostname `localhost` and port `27017` with no network and compass 1.16.3 and it worked fine to me, how is running mongo on your machine?

Comment: @lainatnavi I had two entries for localhost in my hosts file which was causing the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are connected to the internet the DNS service of your device handles the resolution of `localhost`. When you are not connected to the device the only way for your machine to know about the name `localhost` is the `/etc/hosts` file (or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` if you're running windows, latest versions of windows although might resolve localhost without using the hosts file).